# Keeping active background processes in google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am running several instances of ubuntu on google cloud.
Creating ssh tunnels to each instance with this command for every mini-server i have:

```
gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag=-vvv "mini-server-1" --zone="us-central1-f" --ssh-flag="-D:5551" --ssh-flag="-N" --ssh-flag="-n" --ssh-flag="-4" --ssh-flag="-o" --ssh-flag="ServerAliveInterval=5" --ssh-flag="-o" --ssh-flag="ServerAliveCountMax=100000" &
```

Everything works fine, i even added cron job to check if connection is timed out each 10 minutes and restarts it. But when i log out from, seems like every tunnel dies. The script restarts the connections, i can see that from the log, but when i login back, `ps -af | grep ssh` shows nothing

Is there a way to make permanent tunnels that wont die upon logout ?

Comment: I would like to know the answer...

Comment: @Elad663 i solved that with autossh package, check this post https://superuser.com/questions/37738/how-to-reliably-keep-an-ssh-tunnel-open

Comment: thanks. I hope perhaps you found a gcloud command to do it. like any other hpc. I will check it out. currently I use screen..

Answer (score 2):

just exit with Ctrl + D and the process won't die.